# Groupby with when condition in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My data frame looks like

```
    id      |reg_date  |      txn_date|
+----------+----------+--------------------+
|1          |2019-01-06| 2019-02-15 12:51:15|
|1          |2019-01-06| 2019-03-29 13:15:27|
|1          |2019-01-06| 2019-06-01 01:42:57|
|1          |2019-01-06| 2019-01-06 17:01:...|
|5          |2019-06-16| 2019-07-19 11:50:34|
|5          |2019-06-16| 2019-07-13 19:49:39|
|5          |2019-06-16| 2019-08-27 17:37:22|
|2          |2018-07-30| 2019-01-01 07:03:...|
|2          |2018-07-30| 2019-07-30 01:27:57|
|2          |2018-07-30| 2019-02-01 00:08:35
```

I want to pickup the 1st `txn_date` after `reg_date` , i.e. the first `txn_date` of `reg_date >= txn_date`.

Expected output

```
    id      |reg_date  |      txn_date|
+----------+----------+--------------------+
|1          |2019-01-06| 2019-01-06 17:01:...|
|5          |2019-06-16| 2019-07-13 19:49:39|
|2          |2018-07-30| 2019-07-30 01:27:57|
```

I have done so far,

```
df = df.withColumn('txn_date',to_date(unix_timestamp(F.col('txn_date'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp")))

df = df.withColumn('reg_date',to_date(unix_timestamp(F.col('reg_date'),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("timestamp")))

gg = df.groupBy('id','reg_date').agg(min(F.col('txn_date')))
```

But getting wrong results.

Comment: It would be nice if you have prepared the data to create dataframe. What is the output you are getting. ?

Comment: @PIG - there is 2 conditions..one is reg_date>= txn_date another is based on this filter using groupby operation find min.txn_date after reg_date. In my case I got some results which satisfy reg_date< txn_date

Comment: @John Davis Where is column 'mobile' in your df?

Comment: @QuantStats - it's not mobile it's id

Answer (score 0):

The condition `reg_date >= txn_date` can be ambiguous.

Does `2019-01-06>=2019-01-06 17:01:30` mean `2019-01-06 00:00:00>=2019-01-06 17:01:30` or `2019-01-06 23:59:59>=2019-01-06 17:01:30`?

In your example, `2019-01-06>=2019-01-06 17:01:30` is evaluated to be true, so I assume it is the latter case, i.e. the case with 23:59:59.

Proceeding with the assumption above, here is how I coded it.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#create a sample data frame
data = [('2019-01-06','2019-02-15 12:51:15'),('2019-01-06','2019-03-29 13:15:27'),('2019-01-06','2019-01-06 17:01:30'),\
('2019-07-30','2019-07-30 07:03:01'),('2019-07-30','2019-07-30 01:27:57'),('2019-07-30','2019-07-30 00:08:35')]

cols = ('reg_date', 'txn_date')

df = spark.DataFrame(data,cols)

#add 23:59:59 to reg_date as a dummy_date for a timestamp comparison later
df = df.withColumn('dummy_date', F.concat(F.col('reg_date'), F.lit(' 23:59:59')))

#convert columns to the appropriate time data types
df = df.select([F.to_date(F.col('reg_date'),'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('reg_date'),\
F.to_timestamp(F.col('txn_date'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('txn_date'),\
F.to_timestamp(F.col('dummy_date'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('dummy_date')])

#implementation part
(df.orderBy('reg_date')
   .filter(F.col('dummy_date')>=F.col('txn_date'))
   .groupBy('reg_date')
   .agg(F.first('txn_date').alias('txn_date'))
   .show()) 

#+----------+----------------------+
#|  reg_date|              txn_date|
#+----------+----------------------+
#|2019-01-06|   2019-01-06 17:01:30|
#|2019-07-30|   2019-07-30 07:03:01|
#+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to order. You can discard all smaller values with a filter, then aggregate by id and get the smaller timestamp, because the first timestamp will be the minimum. Something like:

```
df.filter(df.reg_date >= df.txn_date) \
  .groupBy(df.reg_date) \
  .agg(F.min(df.txn_date)) \
  .show()
```

Comment: From OP: "I want to pickup the 1st txn_date after reg_date". Ordering does matter if I understand him correctly because he wants the first date that passes the filter even though it may not be the minimum.

Comment: If you order by something, you loose the original order, so it doesn't make sense to take the first after something... Moreover, if you think about big data or spark, you can not assume order in data.

On the other hand, the first date that passes the filter is the earliest date after that filter, so it's the minimum date.